# Silent Fake (F# Make) Console Application

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I would like to run a standalone console application with Fake targets less noisy.

For example

```ml
open Fake.Core
open Fake.IO

let initializeContext () =
    let execContext = Context.FakeExecutionContext.Create false "build.fsx" []
    Context.setExecutionContext (Context.RuntimeContext.Fake execContext)

let runOrDefault args =
    try
        match args with
        | [| target |] -> Target.runOrDefault target
        | _ -> Target.runOrDefault "Run"
        0
    with e ->
        printfn "%A" e
        1

initializeContext()

// *** Define Targets ***
Target.create "Hello" (fun _ ->
  printfn "hello from FAKE!"
)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = runOrDefault args
```

Shell

```bash
-> dotnet run -- Hello

run Hello
bla bla
```

The output should be "hello from FAKE!".

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any knobs to turn this off. For example, [the "Building project with version..." message](https://github.com/fsprojects/FAKE/blob/13e30330cae0597aed6154a95a06d21716b18de3/src/app/Fake.Core.Target/Target.fs#L1153) is [always printed](https://github.com/fsprojects/FAKE/blob/13e30330cae0597aed6154a95a06d21716b18de3/src/app/Fake.Core.Trace/Trace.fs#L91).

You can work around it though by changing what the standard dotnet `printf` functions do with a no-op writer set with [Console.SetOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setout?view=net-7.0), replacing the [default trace listener](https://github.com/fsprojects/FAKE/blob/13e30330cae0597aed6154a95a06d21716b18de3/src/app/Fake.Core.Trace/TraceListener.fs#L374-L375) in FAKE's `CoreTracing`, and explicitly writing to stdout for your result.

```ml
module private ExecutionContext =
  open System
  open System.IO
  open System.Text

  module Out =

    let stdout = Console.Out

    let noop =
      { new TextWriter() with
          override _.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
      }

    /// Supress all logging from FAKE.
    let silence () =
      CoreTracing.setTraceListeners []
      Console.SetOut noop

    let private monitor = Object ()

    /// Print something to stdout.
    let print str =
      lock monitor (fun () ->
        let prev = Console.Out
        Console.SetOut stdout
        printfn $"{str}"
        Console.SetOut prev
      )

let init () =
  Target.create "example" (fun _ ->
    ExecutionContext.Out.print "Hello.")

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  argv
  |> Array.toList
  |> Context.FakeExecutionContext.Create false "build.fsx"
  |> Context.RuntimeContext.Fake
  |> Context.setExecutionContext

  if Array.contains "--silent" argv then
    ExecutionContext.Out.silence ()

  let _ = init ()
  let ctx = Target.WithContext.runOrDefaultWithArguments "build"
  Target.updateBuildStatus ctx

  match Target.results ctx with
  | Ok () -> 0
  | Error _ -> 1
```